# convert to data type DMDATE:datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion

I am working on a SQL database and writing a query.
One condition should restrict data for a date to be between `from date` and `till date`, the column data type is `DMDATE:datetime`,

Query:

```
Select * from dbo.invoices where invoicedate between dateadd(d, -3, getdate()) and getdate()
```

It's always empty, but I should have data for 3 days ago.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter could explain why he disliked the question.

Comment: The term "sql database" is vague.  I could tell by the use of getdate() that you meant sql server, but you should have specified that in the text or tags.  Hover over the sql tag for more info.

Answer (score 1):

getdate() returns date and time, so the time piece could be causing your issue.  casting them to a date type should fix it.

`Select *

from dbo.invoices

where cast(invoicedate as date) between CAST(dateadd(d, -3, getdate()) as date) and CAST(getdate() as date)`

if your invoicedate is already date type than that cast is not necessary.